# Заголовок отображаемой вкладки в TabHost находиться за экраном андроид устройства

Tags: android, android-tabs, fragmenttabhost

Здравствуйте,

при реализации вкладок использую **TabHost**. Он создает что-то типа
ленты с заголовками вкладок (**TabWidget**).

В моем приложении вкладки можно переключать либо нажимая на заголовки вкладок в этой ленте либо путем перелистывании вкладок.

Во втором варианте (перелистывания) при перелистывании создается такая ситуация (вкладок достаточно много и все их заголовки не вмещаются в экран) что на экране отображается вкладка а его заголовок в ленте за экраном.

Как можно переместить ленту с заголовками (**tabWidgets**) так чтобы заголовок отображаемой вкладки был всегда на экране, а не за экраном ?

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос  [в англоязычной версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875939/tabhost-in-scrollview-scroll-to-tab-when-selected). Первый ответ на вопрос помог решить мою проблему. 
Спасибо товарищу @Vania Diezel.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/bg_color"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/bg_color"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
            *app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"*/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Можно по подробнее куда это нужно добавить.

Comment: @foxis обновил ответ

Comment: благодарю за подробности. Только мне желательно использовать именно **TabHost** в качестве вкладок, т.к. приложение у меня готовое и переделывать все приложение под новые виджеты для вкладок не хочется.

Comment: @foxis эх, я так и знал)) ну по крайней мере Вы сможете бурить гугл на основе этого табмода для старой версии. А так, советую таки перейти на новый формат, он более гибкий, да и вообще когда нить все равно придется:)

Comment: Да я уже понял, **TabHost** не лучшее решение для вкладок. Попробую еще поискать, в крайнем случае придется переписывать код под новый виджет.

Comment: Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, ответ указал в вопросе.